# How to show two series out of four in a legend

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I've two buttons which generates a chart in my winForms app. At the right side is a legend with four series. ANy time i click each of the buttons all the four series show up in the legend.

[image]

I wanna show the first two series in the legend if btn1 is clicked & the last two if btn1 is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understend you. You should use `Enable` property for show or hide your series.

For example:

`youChart.Series["Series1"].Enabled = false;`

More property and methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.series%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For your task you can create a button and create event for this button. In event you can hide or show your series, use the series name, how in example above.